# Solve the following system of nonlinear equations by returning to a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Solve the following system of nonlinear equations by returning to a system of linear equations $$\begin{cases}
x&=y^3z \\ 
y &=x^2z^3 \\ 
z & =xy 
\end{cases}$$

Comment: For $x, y, z$ in what space ? Also, do you know a function that conveniently transforms the products in sums ?

Comment: Oh thank you very much. That is the logarithmic formula

Answer (score 2):

First we can notice that $(0, 0, 0)$ is an obvious solution and that in a solution, one of the components is $0$ if and only if they are all equal to $0$. So we can now look at solutions that have all the components different than $0$.

You have
$$\begin{cases}
x&=y^3z \\ 
y &=x^2z^3 \\ 
z & =xy 
\end{cases}$$
and so
$$\begin{cases}
\ln |x|&=3 \ln |y| + \ln|z| \\ 
\ln |y| &= 2 \ln |x| + 3 \ln |z|\ \\ 
\ln |z| & = \ln |x|  + \ln |y| 
\end{cases}$$.

Now you only have to solve this system and to test all the sign combinations.

Edit : The second equation in the first system tells you that $y$ and $z$ have the same sign, and the first one hence tells you that $x$ is non-negative. This reduces greatly the solutions to test at the end.

Comment: The comman of Mathematica `Reduce[x == y^3*z && y == x^2*z^3 && z == x*y, {x, y, z}, Reals]` outputs `(x == 0 && y == 0 && z == 0) || (x == 1 && y == -1 && 
   z == -1) || (x == 1 && y == 1 && z == 1)`.